# Gentílico para quem tem nacionalidade brasileira e americana (EUA)

Tags: gentílicos

Há algum gentílico para quem tem nacionalidade ou origem brasileira e americana (estadunidense) ?

Exemplos de alguns gentílicos de dupla nacionalidade ou origem com o Brasil:

- Ítalo-brasileiro: De origem italiana e brasileira
- Luso-brasileiro: De origem portuguesa e brasileira
- Russo-brasileiro: De origem russa e brasileira
- Franco-brasileiro: De origem francesa e brasileira
- Nipo-brasileiro: De origem japonesa e brasileira
- Teuto-brasileiro: De origem alemã e brasileira
- etc

Comment: "Ítalo" leva acento, no Brasil? Em Portugal acho que não.

Comment: @ANeves: Proparoxítona (Í-ta-lo). Sim. E o priberam também diz que sim: https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/italo

Comment: ... estou sempre a aprender.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O dicionário Houaiss legitima qualquer combinação de ***brasilo-, brasílico-*** ou  ***brasileiro-*** com ***estadunidense*** ou ***norte-americano***. Destas combinações a [Wikipédia (*Imigração Estadunidense no Brasil*)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imigra%C3%A7%C3%A3o_estadunidense_no_Brasil) lista as variantes com *brasilo: **brasilo-estadunidense*** e ***brasilo-norte-americano***, que define como “brasileiro descendente de estadunidenses, ou uma pessoa nascida nos Estados Unidos imigrante no Brasil”, que é perfeitamente extensível a pessoas com dupla nacionalidade.

O dicionário Houaiss apresenta *brasilo-, brasílico-* e *brasileiro-* como antepositivos, que se podem combinar com outros gentílicos:

> **brasílico-** *el.comp.* antepositivo (seguido de hífen, donde a acentuação gráfica), do topónimo Brasil, em compostos do tipo *AFRO-* (ver), cuja lógica lhe é totalmente aplicável; há ainda as alternativas ou variantes *brasilo-* e *brasileiro-*

No verbete *brasileiro-* diz a mesma coisa; em *brasilo-* simplesmente diz que é equivalente a *brasílico-*. No verbet *brasil-*, onde lista tudo o que é derivado, de *brasileira* a *brasilogia*, dá-nos o exemplo:

> **brasil-** [...] *brasilo-guianense* (e vários compostos com *brasilo-* como primeiro elemento)

No Aulete encontrei com a mesma lógica [*brasilo-argentino*](http://www.aulete.com.br/brasilo-argentino) e [*brasilo-uruguaio.*](http://www.aulete.com.br/brasilo-uruguaio)